# WIX service installer CA write access to RegistryKey components

Tags: wix, wix3.10

I have a CA that runs deferred without impersonation in InstallExecuteSequence after PublishProduct.

This CA uses windows impersonation to change context to a local administrative user where the credentials are for queried using a dialog for user input. The elevated requirements are meet, the context is changed and other tasks are performed, however when I try to open a subkey made by the installer for write access in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\NameOfService\MySubKey, I get an exception related to insufficient access. However I can open for read though?

At this point the service has been installed, the key has been created and other values have been written. The context I am using to modify it is a member of the local Administrators group and the session is elevated as per requirements of the other tasks?

Is this a caveat of the windows installer environment?

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, exiting the impersonation back to LocalSystem resolved this. Likely an issue with elevation.